# How can I make my root a flatpage in Django

Tags: django

I'm so sorry if this is obvious.

I've created a flatpage with a URL of `\`. I've created a catchall `(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),` per 'Practical Django Projects'  p17. I get an infinite loop.

I can't see this anywhere I search: how do I make the root index.html a flatpage?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, fixed it. [This conversation](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9678) suggests removing

`(r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls'))`

and keeping (or, in my case, adding!)

`FlatpageFallbackMiddleware`.

Now I have a root flatpage.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Richard, include

```
FlatPageFallBackMiddleware
```

as part of your classes. I did not know how to do this but was able to find [this howto](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/?from=olddocs).

The important thing being removing:

```
url(r'^$', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),
```

from your urls.py and including:

```
'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware',
```

in your settings.py as part of the MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES.